# Evaluating an integral over an elliptical disk

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Using *Mathematica*, I am trying to evaluate the integral $$I=\iint_A xy\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$ over the region $A=\{(x,y): ax^2+2hxy+by^2\le r^2\}$ where  $a>0, ab-h^2>0$.

While trying to do this by hand, I changed variables $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ to get $$I=\iint_{u^2+v^2\le r^2}\left(\frac{uv}{\sqrt{ab-h^2}}-\frac{hv^2}{ab-h^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab-h^2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v$$

Now I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
f[u_, v_] = (u v)/Sqrt[a b - h^2]-(h v^2)/(ab-h^2);
Integrate[f[u, v]*Boole[ u^2 + v^2 <= r^2],
{u, -r, r}, {v, -r, r}, Assumptions -> {a > 0 , ab-h^2 > 0}]
```

By hand, I got $\displaystyle I=-\frac{\pi r^4h}{4(ab-h^2)^{3/2}}$ and I need to check my answer.

I am aware that several of these questions have been asked here before like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-do-i-evaluate-a-double-or-triple-integral-over-a-region?noredirect=1&lq=1) one, to which I reffered. I am a novice as a user of *Mathematica* and I would like to know how to evaluate the likes of these integrals. I changed variables to $(u,v)$ so that I can apply a polar transformation at the end while doing this by hand. But is there a way to directly evaluate general integrals like this in *Mathematica* without changing variables in the first place? If you guide me to a link where this has been answered before then that would be helpful too.

Here are some other links I found but I am not sure which code to use here:

[Evaluation of $ \iint x^2\ dy \ dz$ with ImplicitRegion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159689/evaluation-of-iint-x2-dy-dz-with-implicitregion), [Evaluating a surface integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88203/evaluating-a-surface-integral)

I am using *Mathematica 7.0*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've inconsistently put in/left out spaces, `a b` vs. `ab`.  Also you need the assumption `r > 0`.

```
Integrate[((u v)/Sqrt[a b - h^2] - (h v^2)/(a b - h^2)) Boole[u^2 + v^2 <= r^2],
 {u, -r, r}, {v, -r, r}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, a b - h^2 > 0, r > 0}]
(*  (h π r^4)/(4 (-a b + h^2))  *)
```

---

Using regions, which gives the answer the OP derived by hand:

```
Integrate[
 x y,
 {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[a x^2 + 2 h x y + b y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}], 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, a b - h^2 > 0, r > 0}]
(*  -((h π r^4)/(4 (a b - h^2)^(3/2)))  *)
```

---

Here's a way that might work in V7, but I cannot check.  I relied on the form of cylindrical decomposition that `Reduce` returned, which in this case (of an ellipse) has a simple logical structure.  (There is a way to deal with more complicated cylindrical decompositions that I've used elsewhere, but this was simpler and more easily understood.)

```
dom = Sequence @@ Cases[
   Reduce[
    a > 0 && a b - h^2 > 0 && r > 0 && a x^2 + 2 h x y + b y^2 < r^2,
    {x, y}, Reals],
   _[a_, ___, v : x | y, ___, b_] :> {v, a, b}, (* inequality to iterator *)
 Infinity]
(*
  Sequence[
   {x, -Sqrt[((b r^2)/(a b - h^2))], Sqrt[(b r^2)/(a b - h^2)]},
   {y, -((h x)/b) - Sqrt[(b r^2 - a b x^2 + h^2 x^2)/b^2],
     -((h x)/b) + Sqrt[(b r^2 - a b x^2 + h^2 x^2)/b^2]}
   ]
*)

Integrate[x y, dom, Assumptions -> {a > 0, a b - h^2 > 0, r > 0}]
(*  -((h π r^4)/(4 (a b - h^2)^(3/2)))  *)
```

Comment: I am sorry to bother. Thank you.

Comment: @StubbornAtom It's no bother. :)

Comment: So is there no way to evaluate this without changing variables? The difficulty I guess is that I cannot determine the separate ranges of $x$ and $y$. Is that correct?

Comment: Both give the same answer. So don't think there is anything wrong with the change of variables. Anyway, you have answered all my queries.

Comment: @StubbornAtom OK, I see. A square-root constant is left off the first integral.

Comment: Your new code does work; its showing as a second output after the first one just repeating what the input says.

Answer (score 3):

Another substitution-free method:

```
Simplify[Integrate[x y, {x, y} ∈ Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, Inverse[{{a, h}, {h, b}}/r^2]]],
         a > 0 && b > 0 && r > 0 && a b > h^2]
   -((h π r^4)/(4 (a b - h^2)^(3/2)))
```

Comment: Is it possible that I may not get the desired output in an older version of Mathematica using your code?

Comment: You didn't indicate what version you were using in your question. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I am using version 7.0. I will keep that in mind when I post next time.

Comment: Ah, version 7... I don't think there's a substitution-free route there; Michael's route of rescaling the ellipse to a disk + converting to polar coordinates would be your best bet.

Comment: Many thanks....